# Is it possible to Add XTickLable above and below the Axes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

For Example Here is a Bar plot for some data i was comparing. i was wondering if i could add XTickLable both above and below the X-Axis. It would clarify the plot a lot more.

[image: MATLAB BAR PLOT]

i have tried many things like

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',models(:,1),'XTick',1:numel(models));
hold on
set(gca,'xaxisLocation','top')
set(gca,'XTickLabel',models(:,1),'XTick',1:numel(models));
```

Comment: after changes @Oleg suggested http://i.stack.imgur.com/CD1Cc.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the axes, link them (for zoom, panning...), and flip to the top the `'XAxisLocation'` of the copied one:

```
h = copyobj(gca,gcf);
linkaxes([gca,h])
set(h,'XAxisL','top')
```